# How can I implement this countdown timer in React with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been unsuccessfully trying to convert this vanilla JS countdown timer into React with React hooks.

This is my code in vanilla JS

```
const playBtn = document.querySelector('#play');
const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('#pause');

let counter = 82.5 * 60;
let timePassedElem = document.getElementById('time-passed');

const convertTime = (count) => {
  let hours = Math.floor(count / 3600);
  let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60) - hours * 60;
  let seconds = parseFloat(count % 60).toFixed(0);
  if (hours < 10) hours = `0${hours}`;
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = `0${minutes}`;
  if (seconds < 10) seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};
let intervalId;

playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let startTime = new Date();
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    document.title = convertTime(
      counter + Math.floor((startTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000)
    );
    timePassedElem.innerText = convertTime(
      counter + Math.floor((startTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000)
    );
  }, 200);
});

pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

and this is my try in React hooks but it doesn't work

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [clockTime, setClockTime] = useState(82.5 * 60);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const startTime = useRef();
  const prevDiff = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    startTime.current = new Date().getTime();
    prevDiff.current = 0;
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = convertTime(clockTime);
    let intervalId;
    if (isPlaying) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        const delay = Math.floor((currentTime - startTime.current) / 1000);
        console.log(delay);
        setClockTime(clockTime - delay + prevDiff.current);
        prevDiff.current = delay;
      }, 200);
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [isPlaying, clockTime]);

  const handlePlayClick = () => {
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };

  const handlePauseClick = () => [setIsPlaying(false)];

  const convertTime = (count) => {
    let hours = Math.floor(count / 3600);
    let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60) - hours * 60;
    let seconds = parseFloat(count % 60).toFixed(0);
    if (hours < 10) hours = `0${hours}`;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = `0${minutes}`;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = `0${seconds}`;
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  };
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <span>{convertTime(clockTime)}</span>
      <span>Session</span>
      {isPlaying ? (
        <button onClick={handlePauseClick}>Pause</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handlePlayClick}>Play</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For one, the timer jumps few seconds at the beginning. Second when I press Pause, the timer doesn't resume from where it was left off. Third, the timer is inaccurate, and drifts over time compared to the JS code.

How can I convert my JS code into a working React code with React hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom hook that can be used in those situations. Use it like:

`const [clockTime, isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useCountdown(82.5 * 60);`

inside your component(s). The trick is to use refs to update the milisecond timer internally, to only rerender the integer second when there's a transition (e.g. from 2001.32 to 1998.64) and using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

[image: Edit affectionate-euclid-6ni8g]

```
const useCountdown = (initialTimer, initialPlaying = false) => {
  const milisecond = useRef(initialTimer * 1000);
  const previous = useRef(milisecond);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(initialTimer);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(initialPlaying);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isPlaying || milisecond.current <= 0) return;

    let effectInitialMs = milisecond.current;
    let effectInitialTimeStamp, handle;

    const step = (timestampMs) => {
      if (effectInitialTimeStamp === undefined)
        effectInitialTimeStamp = timestampMs;
      const elapsed = timestampMs - effectInitialTimeStamp;
      milisecond.current = effectInitialMs - elapsed;

      if (milisecond.current <= 0) {
        setTimer(0);
        console.log("cancelAnimationFrame(zero)", handle, milisecond.current);
        cancelAnimationFrame(handle);
      } else {
        const seconds = Math.floor(milisecond.current / 1000);
        const isUpdate = seconds !== Math.floor(previous.current / 1000);
        previous.current = milisecond.current;

        if (isUpdate) {
          setTimer(seconds);
        }

        if (isPlaying) {
          handle = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
      }
    };

    handle = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);

    return () => {
      console.log("cancelAnimationFrame(pause)", handle, milisecond.current);
      cancelAnimationFrame(handle);
    };
  }, [isPlaying]);

  return [timer, isPlaying, setIsPlaying];
};
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be working fine and the important thing the timer seems not to drift over time compared to the vanilla JS app. I need to wrap my head around the details though, as I am not familiar with `requestAnimationFrame` and I don't see at first glance `setInterval` or its recursive equivalent `setTimeout`.